# How to change the TEXT color of header bar and address bar in mobile version of browsers

Tags: css, html, meta-tags, meta

Already using below meta code to change the background color of addressbar in mobile but text color remains black color for some background color.
for eg:
Here I am using orange color for address but if we use black color as background our text change to white color?how text color is working here?

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#f4821f">
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#f4821f">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#f4821f">
```

how to change text color from black to white?

Answer (score 0):

You can change only header bar theme color not text color right now, I think you just have to do that via Custom jQuery functions.